# Efficiency way use implicit subclass in Dart - OOP Polymorphism

Tags: flutter, oop, dart, inheritance, types

I'm a JS dev so in the OOP world I am exactly an idiot guy :smile:

I'm trying to create an Dart library, that have a `parentClass` and a few `subClasses`, then in another class I add a property that has `parentClass` type.
The problem is in this way I must explicit cast that property to `subClass` type when I need to access its specific data.

I wonder does Dart have any efficiency way for this problem or does anyone can advise me another way to make it esier to use when someone using my library?

Sample code:

```
enum GeometryType {
  Point, LineString, Polygon
}

class Geometry {
  final GeometryType type;
  ...
}

class GeometryPoint extends Geometry {
  final type = GeometryType.Point;
  List<List<double>> points;
  ...
}

class GeometryMultiPoint extends Geometry {
  final type = GeometryType.MultiPoint;
  List<List<List<double>>> multiPoints;
  ...
}

class GeometryPolygon extends Geometry {
  final type = GeometryType.Polygon;
  List<List<List<double>>> polygon;
  ...
}
```

Class that using parent class as a property type:

```
class Vector {
  ...
  Geometry geometry;

  factory Vector.withPointGeometry(...) {
    ...
    return Vector(
      geometry: GeometryPoint(points)
    )
  }
  factory Vector.withMultiPointGeometry(...) {
    ...
    return Vector(
      geometry: GeometryMultiPoint(multiPoints)
    )
  }
  ...
}

var vector = Vector.withPointGeometry(...);

var points = vector.geometry.points // points property doesn't exist in `Geometry` instance

var points = (vector.geometry as GeometryPoint).points // Cast worked
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to achieve what you are trying to do using generics.

Example:

```dart
class Vector<E extends Geometry> {
  ...
  E geometry;

  factory Vector.withPointGeometry(...) {
    ...
    return Vector(
      geometry: GeometryPoint(points)
    )
  }
  factory Vector.withMultiPointGeometry(...) {
    ...
    return Vector(
      geometry: GeometryMultiPoint(multiPoints)
    )
  }
  ...
}
```

Using this way to create your `Vector` class you will receive a `Vector<GeometryPoint>` when calling the `Vector.withPointGeometry` factory. Now that the `geometry` property has a specific subtype of `Geometry` you will not need to cast it anymore.

**Please go ahead and read [this article](https://dart.academy/generics-in-dart-and-flutter/) about generics for a more complete answer.**
Specifically the section "Creating generic classes" might be of use for you.